# How can I add flashing effect to an option tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select tag and option tags inside as below.

```
<select>
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">second</option>
    <option value="third">Third</option>
</select>
```

I want to flash the "second" option tag to flash once when the select tag was selected and expands the option tags.

How do I do that in pure javascript or css?

Comment: What does flash mean?  If it means blink you can find some CSS/Pure JS/jQuery solutions in wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink It's been deprecated.

Comment: Don't use the blink tag, it is deprecated and can't be trusted to work.   The wikipedia page I linked shows alternatives, as well as some information about why blinking effects are not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css3 solution.  Either change the selectors or add 'blink' class to elements you want to blink.

```
.blink {
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite
  -o-animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite
}

@-webkit-keyframes .blink {
  67% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-moz-keyframes .blink {
  67% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-o-keyframes .blink {
  67% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes .blink {
  67% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Pure JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function blink() {
    var blinks = document.getElementsByTagName('blink');
    for (var i = blinks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var s = blinks[i];
      s.style.visibility = (s.style.visibility === 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    }
    window.setTimeout(blink, 1000);
  }
  if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", blink, false);
  else if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", blink, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", blink);
  else window.onload = blink;
</script>
<blink>Text to blink here</blink>
```

Although frankly I'm not sure why that example insists on using the blink element.   I would just stick with the HTML you have and change the JS to suit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo-class with [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) and CSS animations.

This example will blink the background when the `select` is focused, such as when it is clicked on to expand it.

Unfortunately, this does not appear to work in all browser and OS combinations due to limitation in some browsers, but it works in browsers that let you style select options.

### Working Example:

```css
select:focus option:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-animation: flash 0.25s 2 alternate;
       -moz-animation: flash 0.25s 2 alternate;
            animation: flash 0.25s 2 alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% {
        background: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        background: red;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes flash {
    0% {
        background: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        background: red;
    }
}
@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        background: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="first">First</option>
    <option value="second">second</option>
    <option value="third">Third</option>
</select>
```